# Не могу реализовать удаление из корзины без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Аjax запрос

```
    $('.cart__item').on('click','.del_item', function(){

    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cart/delete',
        data: {id: id},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res){
             $('.cart_block').replaceWith(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Errывывor!');
        }
        
    });
});
```

Первое удаление проходит как надо, а удаление следующего элемента уже только после перезагрузки страницы

Пробовал

```
     $('.cart_block').html(res);
```

так все элементы удаляются по очереди, без перезагрузки, Но, это ломает к чертям разметку, пшто на старую накладывается новый html

Comment: Измените тип запроса type: 'POST'

Comment: @KordDEM ,  а иначе никак?

Comment: приведите пример html кода.

Comment: у вас наверное структура `.cart_block .cart_item .del_item` ? заменяя тело `.cart_block` у вас отпадают все обработчики `.cart_item click`

Comment: @teran похоже на то, но как сделать правильно мне в голову не приходит

Comment: навесить обработчик on('click','.del_item')` на родительский `$(".cart_block")` а не `.cart_item`

Comment: @teran о точно, спасибо большое!

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предположу, что ваша структуру DOM выглядит как `.cart_block => .cart_item => .del_item`. Текущий обработчик удаления привязан к имеющимся `.cart_item`. Когда родительский блок заменяется новым контентом результатами аякса, то все `.cart_item` удаляются вместе со своими обработчиками, поэтому обработчики надо привязывать к этому `.cart_block`, который никуда не исчезает из DOM.

```
 $(".cart_block").on("click", ".del_item", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();            // если .del_item это <a class="del_item">
 });
```